# How to check if the character under the cursor is a tab?

Tags: vimscript, tab-characters

I am using the code `getline(".")[col(".")-1]` to get the character under the cursor. How can I check if the character under the cursor is a tab ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just compare the character you got with a tab, which can be represented with the `\t` escape sequence. That is,

```
getline(".")[col(".")-1] == "\t"
```

The expression will return 1 if the character is tab, 0 if not.